# Select the <form> element from an <input> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the `<form>` element from an `<input>` element with JQuery. I've tried this:

```
$(".inputClass").parent("form")
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `$(".inputClass").closest("form")` because the `form` may not be the direct parent of the input element

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Thank you. It works. If you post it like an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$(".inputClass").closest("form")` because the `form` may not be the direct parent of the input element

Comment: It is possible for a form element to [not be a descendant of the form at all](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form), so this won't always work.

Comment: But this is enough for me.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas in at least 95%(?) case, it's true, this is enough

Answer (score 8):

In HTML 4 you can grab the *ancestor* that is a form element (by using `parents` (plural)), but HTML 5 allows a form control to be [associated with a form that it not its ancestor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form), so you can't rely on that.

Form controls have [a `form` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-63239895) that will give you their associated form element.

```
var form = $(".inputClass").prop("form");
```

You can turn it into a jQuery object if you like.

```
var $form = $( form );
```

Or in one line:

```
var $form = $( $(".inputClass").prop("form") );
```

Comment: Never knew this existed. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the "form" property available to every form field.

```
var input = document.getElementById("foo");

var form = input.form;
```

No jQuery needed. Just good old fashioned DOM.